# Flip the TabBar and subView in ViewController iOS

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, core-animation

I am working on an app which is using `UITabBarController`. At some point, I have to flip the view and the whole `tabbar` and also have to update the `tabbar` items.

To flip the views without `tabbar`, I have used this:

```
-(IBAction)flipView:(id)sender {

    if (self.isSignUpViewOnDisplay == YES) {

        [self.signUpView setHidden:YES];
        [self.signUpView setHidden:NO];

        [UIView transitionFromView:self.signUpView toView:self.signInView
                          duration:1.0
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                        completion:NULL];
        self.isSignUpViewOnDisplay = NO;
    }
    else {

        [self.signUpView setHidden:NO];
        [self.signUpView setHidden:YES];

        [UIView transitionFromView:self.signInView toView:self.signUpView
                          duration:1.0
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                        completion:NULL];
        self.isSignUpViewOnDisplay = YES;
    }
}
```

And it works perfectly. Now, I am inside a `tabbar` and I have to flip it. By using same code, I cannot see the flip animation. Although, `tabbar` is updated and its simple.

How I can flip the whole `tabbar` with current controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply flip it with *tabBarController.tabBar*

```
UIView * a = self.tabBarController.tabBar;

[UIView transitionFromView:toolbar
                    toView:a
                  duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {

 }];
```